# Show for i' that ∀x x' + i' = x + i''

Tags: logic

I am given the following...

When $i = 0$ $\forall x\colon x' + 0 = x + 0'$

Assume it holds that $\forall x\colon x' + i = x + i'$

Show that $\forall x\colon x' + i' = x + i''$

My tools are the axioms of Q
The only ones that seem relevant are

Q1 : $\forall x\forall y(x'= y' \to x = y)$
Q4 : $\forall x x + 0  = x$
Q5 : $\forall x\forall y x + y' = (x + y)'$

I've been trying this for a while and these were my attempted solutions

1
$x' + i' = x + i''$

$x + 0' + i' = x + i''$ by Q4

from here I tried to to let $i' = y$ to get

$x + (y + 0')  = x + y'$

$x + (y + 0)' = x + y'$ by Q4

$x + (y)'= x + y'$

$x + y' = x + y'$

setting $y = i'$

$x + i'' = x + i''$

Not sure if this was the right way.

Comment: I'm afraid that Robinson's arithmetic isn't commutative; so you cannot get $x + (y+0') \;\text{from}\; x+(0' +y)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting with the logical truth:
$$x'+i'=x'+i'$$
then
$$x'+i'=x'+(i+0)'\;\;\text{by Q4}$$

can you continue? let me know and I'll go further.

edit after your comment:
in order to format formulae in Tex you can place them between two dollar signs. "$"

edit 2, the full answer:

The next obvious step in the proof is applying Q5 to get the equation:

$$x'+i'=x'+i+0'\;\;\text{by Q5}$$ 
$$x'+i'=x+i'+0'\;\;\text{by the induction hypothesis}$$ 
$$x'+i'=x+(i'+0)'\;\;\text{by Q5}$$ 
$$x'+i'=x+(i')'\;\;\text{by Q4}$$

Which is the desired result.

Comment: x' + i' = x' + i + 0' by Q1

x' + i' = x' + 0'  + 0' by Q1 

x' + i = x + 0' + 0' + 0' by Q1

Sorry, I'm not familiar with the formatting on here, I'm still trying to work through and see what the possible options are though.

Comment: *by Q5 but YES!

then what?

Comment: I've made an edit to my answer.

Comment: Disregard the first comment let me take another shot.

x' + i' = x'  + (i + 0)' by Q4
x' + i' = x' + i + 0' by Q5?

Not sure where to go from here

Comment: check the inductive hypothesis :-)

Comment: you're assuming that $$x' + i = x + i'$$

Comment: OH. So Once you get to x' + i + 0' you use the assumption and restate it as 
x' + i' = x + i' + 0' which can be reduced to x + i''?

Comment: Don't be hasty, first you need another application of Q5 to get $x+(i'+0)'$ on the right side, which in turns becomes $x+i''$ by Q4. And that's the desired result!

Comment: If everything is clear I'll write down the full answer.

Comment: Perfectly clear. I wrote the intermittent step down on my paper but i was too hasty to include it in the comment. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Yeah no, that does not prove anything; indeed I could have stated ahead of time that $x + S(S(i)) = x + S(S(i))$ without knowing anything about the successor function $S$: it is tautologically true. But what you are being asked to prove is a very deep fact, which is that the addition functions defined by

```
data N = Zero | S N

add1 a Zero = a
add1 a (S n) = S (add1 a n)

add2 a Zero = a
add2 a (S n) = add2 (S a) n
```

are both the same function. (In fact this matters a lot for computer programmers because it turns out that in many computer programming languages `add1` wastes a precious resource called the “call stack” whereas `add2` is “tail-recursive” and so it can be optimized to a loop to not waste this particular resource.)

You want to use two facts here:

1. If $A = B$ then $S(A) = S(B).$ This does not appear as an axiom  because it does not need to, it is part of what it means for two things to be equal: they must in all ways be indistinguishable including by applying any function to them.
2. If $A = S(b + c)$ then $A = b + S(c).$ This is part of the definition of addition but you normally use it the forwards way, going from $b + S(c)$ to $S(b + c).$ I am telling you that because these two entities are equal, you can also use it in this reverse way. Equals signs are nondirectional.

Starting from the given assumption about $S(x) + i = x + S(i),$ apply $S(\bullet)$ to both sides per the first fact and then use the reasoning of the second fact to get to your desired happy place.